# Exception caught in Netty in play framework

Tags: scala, web-applications, playframework

I have created a new play framework app in SCALA. If i run the application it runs as expected and i am able to open the URL localhost:9000, but after i created a lib folder and added some jars(spark jars) in that when i tries to run the application using the command play run, it shows the message

```
[error] p.nettyException - Exception caught in Netty
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$.empty()Lscala/collection/immutable/HashSet;
        at akka.actor.ActorCell$.<init>(ActorCell.scala:305) ~[akka-actor_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
        at akka.actor.ActorCell$.<clinit>(ActorCell.scala) ~[akka-actor_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
        at akka.actor.RootActorPath.$div(ActorPath.scala:152) ~[akka-actor_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
        at akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider.<init>(ActorRefProvider.scala:465) ~[akka-actor_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
        at akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider.<init>(ActorRefProvider.scala:453) ~[akka-actor_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
[error] p.nettyException - Exception caught in Netty
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution$
```

when i tries to open the URL localhost:9000 it shows "localhost page is not working".

Spark Version 2.0
Scala Version 2.10 and also i have tested with scala 2.11 and 2.12 same error reproducing.

Play framework version - 2.2.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you created a new Play! project, why use version 2.2? The newest one is 2.5 and that may already fix your issue.

Second, to ensure you don't have any other version conflicts I suggest you use managed dependencies instead of putting them manually into the `lib` folder.

For Apache Spark, you would add this line to your `build.sbt` file:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0"
```

as described in Spark's [Quick Start Guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html). You need to use Scala 2.10 or 2.11 (suggested) in your project.

If that doesn't resolve your issue, please post the contents of your `build.sbt` and the controller code. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks ! That's worked great. Just upgraded to Play 2.5.